# How to plot multiple histograms at once of specific columns within dataset R

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram, lapply

I am using the R dataset "USArrests" and am trying to plot the histograms of each column. However, when I do this, I am not able to figure out how to put the xaxis label as well as the title for each histogram labeling the variable that I am looking at.

I currently have

```
attach(USArrests)
lapply(arrests[,c(1:4)], FUN = hist)
```

The four histograms outputted look like this:
[image: Histogram of Murder]

How can I add the axis/title labels? Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use base R `hist`? This can be done using `ggplot` and facets. Unrelated: use of `attach` is discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use base R, this is an occasion where a for-loop is better than lapply.

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for(i in names(USArrests))
  hist(USArrests[[i]], main = i, xlab = "Value")
```

[image]

You could also use `tidyr` and `ggplot2` with facets, but would need to experiment with the histogram bin size.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

USArrests %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free")
```

[image]